# How to clear specific cache inside ehcache

Tags: ehcache

how to clear a particular cache in ehcache ?
Say I have the following cache configured in ehcache.
1) OfficeMgtCache
2) BranchMgtCahce
3) EmployeeCache

I need to clear the cache of BranchMgtCahce part alone. (Should not remove this cache.but just clear the cache contents)

I have found clearAll() in CacheManager. But this will clear all the caches present.

Comment: Same class API has method named <code> clearAllStartingWith(String prefix) </code> which does what you are looking for!

Comment: I have similar cache names in my application. For instance , I have two caches say EmployeeCahce and EmployeCacheForOtherBranch. If I need to clear EmployeeCache using <code> clearAllStartingWith(String prefix) </code> , both the cache will be cleared. But I need only the EmployeeCahce to be cleared and not the EmployeCacheForOtherBranch cache.

Comment: Then you know the answer - use a better naming scheme!